# Sum of a matrix, even or odd

Tags: python

This function receives a numeric matrix represented as a list of rows, where each row is in turn a list. Assume that  it is a square matrix:  all rows have the same length and there are as many rows as elements in each row. Also assume that the matrix is at least of dimension 2 by 2 (i.e. minimally the matrix has  2 rows with 2 elements each)
The function should return a list with as many elements as number of rows. Element i in the resulting list should have the sum of the values in row i.

For example, if the matrix is

```
1   2   3
10  20  30
100 200 300
```

then this function should return the list `[6,60,600]`

That is, 
`addValuesInAllRows( [ [1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300] ] )`   should return `[6,60,600]`

Isn't this sort of similar but how would you sum up the list individually

Comment: You've changed your question so much that now all these answers are invalid.

Comment: I don't understand how to add the row whole row together because I keep getting error

Comment: @user1790201 - Read the answers people have written for you, there are solutions for both of your questions.

Comment: Or I mean the individual lists together, than returning them all together

Answer (score 4):

```
matrix = [ [1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300] ]
print [sum(row) for row in zip(*matrix)]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Sum of columns**

```
>>> def addValuesInAllCols(arr):
      return [sum(x) for x in zip(*arr)]

>>> addValuesInAllCols( [ [1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300] ] )
[111, 222, 333]
```

**Sum of rows**

```
>>> map(sum, [ [1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300] ] )
[6, 60, 600]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option:

```
from operator import itemgetter

matrix = [ [1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300] ]

def addValuesInAllCols(arr):
    return map(sum, [map(itemgetter(i), arr) for i in range(len(a))])
```

Where [map is a build-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) that can be rewritten as a simple for. For ex:

`[map(itemgetter(i), arr) for i in range(len(a))]` is the same as:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    tmp = []
    for row in a:
        tmp.append(row[i])
    result.append(tmp)
```

Edited per new tests:

```
def addValuesInAllCols(arr):
    return map(sum, arr)
```

Or without map:

```
def addValuesInAllCols(arr):
    return [sum(row) for row in arr]
```

Comment: I can't use imported functions, but I can see where this is going but what does map do?

Comment: I used your alternate function without map, and for the example I showed above I got [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]] instead of [6, 60 , 600]

Comment: @user1790201 that  sample is for your very first sample that you changed than. The same for new tests is 'return [sum(row) for row in arr]'

Comment: @user1790201 you are welcome, if my post was helpful - vote it)))